# Can we have a badge for "you've answered N questions" or something along those lines?

Tags: feature-request, badges

After 10 years on SO I've noticed that I've just answered 1,000 questions and feel very accomplished. I feel I need a medal or a badge or something.

My feel is that this would reward loyal users who have supported other site users over many years. Thoughts?

Maybe:

- Bronze badge for 10 answers
- Silver badge for 100 answers
- Gold badge for 1,000 answers

Comment: This seems to prioritize quantity over quality.  I'd agree with you with the stipulation that the answers must at least have a positive net score, of a value of maybe at least 3 or something.  I'm not sure on the exact value, but I feel it should exist.

Comment: We kind of already have this with tag badges, which count both quantity and score so they mostly avoid the problem Daedalus mentioned.

Comment: Maybe it could just use the value pairs from tag badges, but have it not be tag-specific.  20 answers totaling 100 score gets you bronze, 80 answers totaling 400 score gets you silver, and 200 answers totaling 1000 score gets you gold.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the proposal to explain why it is beneficial to the site? In particular what behavior these badges would encourage that is not yet covered by similar tag-specific badges? ("I feel I need ..." is extremely poor justification for FR from my point of view)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The only badges with some value are the tag badges, the rest is just gamification fluff (okay, I guess there is also some value for moderator elections the one or two times a year they happen). Given the large pile of pretty pointless badges that already exist it is kind of random to demand an explanation for more pointless badges. To have more of them, naturally!

Comment: The reputation points are made for this purpose. If you really helped the community you will get rewarded with upvotes/points. If not, it doesn't really matter how many answers you have. I see people repeating the same answer again and again to trivial duplicates.

Comment: We do have one badge that supports quantity over quality, https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The purpose of Silver and Gold badges is to encourage behaviour that's useful (or possibly discourage behaviour that isn't useful).

We already have badges for high scoring answers i.e. Nice Answer, Good Answer and Great Answer.

What those badges do is encourage you to write an excellent answer and then if you come across that same question again, to mark the question as duplicate of the question you answered previously. That way

1. You point more people to your excellent answer, that they may be enlightened by it and possibly also upvote it.
2. You avoid having to repeat your answer again and again and again, thereby saving you time and allowing you to answer other unrelated questions.

If we have badges merely for the quantity rather than the quality of answers then we're encouraging quantity over quality and we'd get

1. fewer questions marked as duplicates as people would be incentivised to answer the same questions again and again and we already have quite enough of that.
2. fewer answers to distinct questions as we'd have people typing the same answer in again and again rather than figuring out how to answer something new.

I'd rather encourage quality than quantity and for these reasons I really don't think this is a good idea.